# Social login not working in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

```
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Oauth/Http.php(190): Zend_Oauth_Http->_assessRequestAttempt(Object(Zend_Http_Response))
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Oauth/Http.php(191): Zend_Oauth_Http->startRequestCycle(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Oauth/Http.php(191): Zend_Oauth_Http->startRequestCycle(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Oauth/Http/RequestToken.php(51): Zend_Oauth_Http->startRequestCycle(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Oauth/Consumer.php(115): Zend_Oauth_Http_RequestToken->execute()
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Magestore/Sociallogin/controllers/TwloginController.php(130): Zend_Oauth_Consumer->getRequestToken()
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Magestore/Sociallogin/controllers/TwloginController.php(8): Magestore_Sociallogin_TwloginController->getAuthorization()
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Magestore_Sociallogin_TwloginController->loginAction()
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /var/www/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

These are the error messages I got when I tried logging in using Twitter login. Can someone tell me the proper steps for setting up the social login and make it work?

Comment: Please post the relevant code that you already have, that will help us help you.

Comment: Where is the error message? You pasted only the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issue when I first setup CedSocialLogin for Twitter but I discovered that it wasn't a programming issue but my own error in inserting the Tokens!
MAKE SURE THERE IS NO SPACE BEFOFE THE APP ID AND APP SECRET.[Sample configuration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JabUF.png)